# Upon upgrade to chromedriver 2.30, error: cannot parse capability: chromeOptions/cannot parse mobileEmulation/'Apple iPhone 6' must be a valid device

Tags: rspec, capybara, selenium-chromedriver, device-emulation

In our Capybara/Rspec suite written in Ruby, we use a special driver to test touch interactions and mobile screen sizes.

This code works in Chromedriver 2.28

our setup in spec/spec_helper.rb

```
Capybara.register_driver :chrome_emulating_iphone_6 do |app|
  mobile_emulation = { "deviceName" => "Apple iPhone 6" }
  caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
    'chromeOptions' => {
      'mobileEmulation' => mobile_emulation,
      'args' => [ ' --disable-web-security' ]
    }
  )
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome,
                                 :desired_capabilities => caps)
end
```

The above code worked in Chromedriver 2.28

checking exact version:

```
$ chromedriver -v
ChromeDriver 2.28.455517 (2c6d2707d8ea850c862f04ac066724273981e88f)
```

Upon upgrading to Chromedriver 2.30, the code above breaks
the version after upgrading that seems to have broken the spec:

```
$ chromedriver -v
ChromeDriver 2.30.477690 (c53f4ad87510ee97b5c3425a14c0e79780cdf262)
```

the ruby spec fails with:

1) sister selector view Mobile Sister Selector should be on the page
     Failure/Error: visit "/products/boxer-briefs"

```
 Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError:
   unknown error: cannot parse capability: chromeOptions
   from unknown error: cannot parse mobileEmulation
   from unknown error: 'Apple iPhone 6' must be a valid device
   from unknown error: must be a valid device
     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477690 (c53f4ad87510ee97b5c3425a14c0e79780cdf262),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.6 x86_64)
```

Answer (score 1):

A full list of acceptable device names can be found [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/167a7f5e03f8b9bd297d2663ec35affa0edd5076/third_party/WebKit/Source/devtools/front_end/emulated_devices/module.json). Additional information about mobile device emulation can be found on the ChromeDriver web site at https://chromedriver.chromium.org/mobile-emulation.

Comment: Alas, the first link is broken and the second is not really helpful. I guess now you just quess supported devices :-D

Comment: I have fixed the link to the list of acceptable device names. Sorry about the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with changing

```
mobile_emulation = { "deviceName" => "Apple iPhone 6" }
```

to

```
mobile_emulation = { "deviceName" => "iPhone 6" }
```